# Como conseguir um IResource de um ICompilationUnit

Tags: java, eclipse

Estou fazendo um plugin no eclipse e quando seleciono uma classe java no *Package Explorer* acabo recebendo um objeto do tipo **ICompilationUnit**, mas preciso de um **IResource**, o que pode ser feito ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tente o método `getUnderlyingResource()`:

```
  public IResource obterIResourceDe(ICompilationUnit unit) {
    return unit.getUnderlyingResource();
  }
```

da documentação [Javadoc](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/ntopic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/IJavaElement.html#getUnderlyingResource%28%29).

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente.